# removeNull() is causinng issues with my array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

I am making a roster class that holds Students (Objects) in it. I am supposed to put them all in an array without any null elements but when I use my removeNull() method it adds the last Student in the array twice. does anyone know how I can fix this issue? I think that it is related to the remove null method because when I don't use it I don't have this issue except my array is full of nulls. (However many nulls there were is how many times the last student  gets added to the array) would be great if someone knew how to fix this, I've tried everything

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Roster {
    
    private Object [] array = new Student [10];
    private LinkedList <Student> roster = new LinkedList<Student>();
    private int counter = 0;
    
    public Roster (Student student) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        addStudent(student);
    }

    public Student[] getArray() {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        return (Student[]) array;
    }

    public void setArray(Student[] array) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        this.array = array;
    }

    public LinkedList<Student> getRoster() { // O(1) this runs in constant time
        return roster;
    }

    public void setRoster(LinkedList<Student> roster) {// O(1) this runs in constant time
        this.roster = roster;
    }
    
    public Object[] sort() { //O(n^2) runs n^2 times for the nested for loop
        array = roster.toArray();
        removeNull();
            for(int i =0; i < counter; i++) { // O(n)
                for(int j =1; j < counter - i; j++) // O(n)
                if((((Student) array[j - 1]).compareTo((Student) array[j])) >= 1) {
                    Student temp = (Student) array[j-1];
                    array[j-1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return array;
    } 

    public void loadRoster() { // O(n) executes the length of the array
        removeNull();
        for(int i =0; i< array.length; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    
    public void addStudent(Student student) { // O(n) toArray()
        if(counter > 10) {
            System.out.println("Sorry the class is full");
        }
        else {
            roster.add(student);
            array = roster.toArray();
            counter++;
            loadRoster();
            System.out.println("Student added");
        }
    }
    
    public void removeStudent(String ID) { // O(n) toArray()
        if(counter <= 0)
            System.out.println("The class is empty");
        else {
            roster.remove(IDSearch(ID));            
            array = roster.toArray();
            counter--;
            loadRoster();
        }
    }
    public void removeNull() {
        int k = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (array[i] != null)
                array[k++] = (Student) array[i];
        }   
    }

    public Student IDSearch( String IDNumber) {  // O(n) runs the for loop
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
            if(((Student) array[i]).getIDNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(IDNumber)) {
                System.out.print(array[i]);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                return (Student) array[i];
            }
        
        System.out.println("Student not found");
        return null;
    }
    
    public Student nameSearch(String lastName , String firstName) { // O(n) for loop for array length
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length;i++)
            if((((Student) array[i]).getLastName().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) && (((Student) array[i]).getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
                return (Student) array[i];
            }
        System.out.print("Student not found");
        return null;    
    }
    
    public void save() { // constant time
        removeNull();
        sort();
        loadRoster();
    }

    public void saveChanges() throws FileNotFoundException{ // O(n) for loop to print to the new file
        save();
        File file = new File ("studentList.txt");
        
        if (file.exists())
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
        for(int i =0; i <array.length; i++)
            out.println(array[i]);
        
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not adding the last student twice; rather, the last student was never moved.  You should be getting behavior like this:

```
old list:  [s1,  s2,  null, s3,  s4 ]
new list:  [s1,  s2,  s3,  s4,  (s4) ]
```

When you remove null, and shift appropriately, the total size of the list does not change. You need to afterwards reduce the size of your list appropriately.
As an aside, there is no need to cast to `(Student)` in this loop; type casts are generally something you should avoid, and here it doesn't buy you anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you create the array from the list, why don't you remove the nulls from the list and recreate the array?  Something like this:

```
roster.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
array = roster.toArray();
```